# C++ Constructor code...what is this called?

Tags: c++, constructor

This is what I found in a program's code:

```
pff::NAS::NAS( const NAS& p_Other ) 
: pff::MCCI(_T("NAS"))           //<- ?
, m_strS(_T("JustAString"))      //<- ?
, m_strK(_T("JustAString"))      //<- ?
, m_strR(p_Other.GetmystrR())    //<- ?
, m_Swap()
{ }
```

**And my Question is:**
What are those (`//<- ?`)-marked lines called? I'd love to search for what its supposed to do and why the person who did this code used it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called initialization list.

More information in the excellent FAQ http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html

Answer (score 4):

This is called **Initializer list**. It is used to initialize the values of the class/struct member variables. You can see more about this in [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) nice article.

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are initializing the variables for that object

i.e.

```
pff::MCCI  (inherited)
m_strS 
m_str
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are for initializing your fields in the class.
This is how it is done:

```
class MyClass{
private:
    int my_int;
public:
    MyClass(int a):my_int(a){}
```

the my_int field contains now the value of a.
What you do is calling the constructor of the field you want to initialize.